# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln \left(1+3 \sin ^{2} x\right) d x$

Tags: definite-integrals

I need a hint for evaluating $$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln \left(1+3 \sin ^{2} x\right) d x$$
I've stumbled upon this integral which is from a calculus textbook of mine and I have no idea how to solve it. I don't see how a substitution would do the work here. Any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(1+\alpha\sin^2 x)\, dx=\pi \ln \frac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775206/integral-int-0-pi-2-ln1-alpha-sin2-x-dx-pi-ln-frac1-sqrt1-alp)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parametric integral with $a \geq 0$ :
$$
F(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln \left(1+a \sin ^{2} x\right) d x
$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
F^{\prime}(a) &=\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \ln \left(1+a \sin ^{2} x\right) d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\sin ^{2} x}{1+a \sin ^{2} x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Also, note that $F(0)=0$ and solve for $F(a)$ by integrating both sides of what you've ended up with for $F^{\prime}(a)$ from  $0$ to $a$. Can you take it from here?