# How to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(2k+1)!!}{(k+1)(2k+2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha^{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, factorial

I was trying to solve the integral [$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(1+\alpha\sin^2 x)\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775206/integral-int-0-pi-2-ln1-alpha-sin2-x-dx-pi-ln-frac1-sqrt1-alp?noredirect=1), where $\alpha>-1$

And my approach is using infinite sum by expanding $\ln(1+\alpha\sin^2 x)$

So let $I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(1+\alpha\sin^2 x)\, dx$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\alpha^{k+1}\sin^{2k+2} x}{k+1}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2k+2} x dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1}\frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k+2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
I'm stuck at this summation

**Edit 1:** I'm interested in solving the sum, please do not suggest to solve the integral the other way around as in the link I provided already has sufficient of them

**Edit 2:** I evaluated $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2k+2} x dx$ wrong. I also add the domain for $\alpha$.

Comment: What makes you think that this approach works?

Comment: @KBS I'm just curious. Also I believe $\frac{(-\alpha)^{k+1}\sin^{2k+2} x}{k+1}$ is uniformly converge to 0 thus the interchanging of summation and integral is allowable. If we input it into Wolfram, we can actually get an answer. The same as in the solution to the initial problem. But yeah, it seems we have to put a domain to $\alpha$, which I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
Where $$(1+x)^{-1/2}-1
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {2k \choose k} (\frac{-x}{4})^k=F(x),  \quad |x|<1.$$
$$\frac{2I}{\pi}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(2k+1)!!}{(k+1)(2k+2)!!}a^{k+1}=- \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {2k+2 \choose k+1}\frac{(-a/4)^{k+1}}{k+1}=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{2k \choose k}\frac{(-a/4)^{k}}{k}. $$
$$\frac{2}{\pi}I=-\int_{0}^{a} \frac{F(z)}{z} dz=-\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+z}}{z\sqrt{1+z}}dz=2\int_{\infty}^{1/\sqrt{a}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}-\frac{1}{u}\right) du, z=1/u^2$$ $$\implies I =\pi\ln \left({1+\sqrt{1+1/u^2}}\right)_{\infty}^{1/\sqrt{a}}=\pi\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1+a}}{2}.$$